# How to set up a Seeeduino with LoRaWAN?

Tags: arduino, lorawan

I'm trying to implement communication between a Seeeduino LoRaWAN and The Rhings Network. The gateway is set up, however I've been unable to load the correct LoRaWAN information onto the Seeeduino.

I've been following [the tutorial](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Seeeduino_LoRAWAN/) from their website. The Seeeduino does connect and I can upload code onto the Seeeduino to read and print sensor data via serial, so the IDE settings, like the board should be correct.

Problem 1: library LoRaWan.h is not known.
Problem 2: When using a different Beelan Lorawan library, the library import works, but commands such as lora.getversion, lora.setid, etc. cause an error, because they don't exist.

So the main question really is, how do I let the Seeeduino know which AppSKey, DevEUI, AppEUI, etc. it should use?

```c
#include <LoRaWan.h>

void setup(void) {     
    Serial.begin(115200);
    lora.init();
    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    lora.getVersion(buffer, 256, 1);
    SerialUprint(buffer); 
    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    lora.getId(buffer, 256, 1);
    Serial.print(buffer);

    // void setId(char *DevAddr, char *DevEUI, char *AppEUI);
    lora.setId(NULL, "12409E2345695432", "70B3D57EF0006593");
    // setKey(char *NwkSKey, char *AppSKey, char *AppKey);
    lora.setKey(NULL, NULL, "47BDA77B6D7B4DDA7DC182E54295FE4E");
}

void loop(void) {   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the newer 1.5.6 board version. Reverting to board version 1.3 of Seeed SAMD Boards installed the missing LoRaWaN library and allowed for a successfull setup of the lorawan components.